# Repeat a letter twice after every four cells

Tags: excel

Is there a formula I can use that will print the letter `R` after every four cells?

For example,

```
A1  B1  C1  D1  E1  F1  G1  H1  I1  J1  K1  L1
-   -   -   -    R  R   -   -   -   -   R   R
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want your pattern to begin in column A:

```
=REPT("R",NOT(MOD(COLUMNS($A:A),6))+NOT(MOD(COLUMNS($A:A)+1,6)))
```

If you wish the pattern to begin in another column, replace the references to 'A' with that column.

Comment: This works, thanks. What if I want to change it so that R would be repeated every 6 cells? How will the formula change?

Comment: To clarify... do you mean five blank cells between double R's ?

Comment: If so, like this:  `=REPT("R",NOT(MOD(COLUMNS($A:A),7))+NOT(MOD(COLUMNS($A:A)+1,7)))`

Comment: my solution works, too, but this is pretty darn sweet!

Answer (score 3):

Since the other two answers do not fully address the OP's **whole** question (based on title, text and example) of inserting the letter `R` twice after 4 blank cells, I am providing this solution.

Start in cell E1 with the formula and drag over. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

`=REPT("R",OR(MOD(COLUMNS($A:A),6)={0,5}))`

Regards